# How can I block in my Qt application signal SIGSEGV from cURL library?

Tags: c++, c, qt, curl, crash

My Qt app uses cURL library to send HTTP requests and sometimes cURL sends SIGSEGV and after that my app crashes.
Is it possible to catch this signal and prevent segmentation fault ?

Comment: It is actually other way around: SIGSEGV is sent because your application has crashed.

Comment: See also [How can I solve segmentation fault in library curl without setting option CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL=1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021827/how-can-i-solve-segmentation-fault-in-library-curl-without-setting-option-curlop)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR:

Don't attempt to block or ignore SIGSEGV. It will just bring you pain.

## Explanation:

SIGSEGV means very bad things have happened, and your program has wandered into memory that it is not allowed to access. This means your program is utterly hosed.

Pardon my Canadian.

Your program is broken. You can't trust it to behave in any rational fashion anymore and should actually thank that SIGSEGV for letting you know this. As much as you don't want to see SIGSEGV, it's a hell of a lot better than the alternative of a broken program continuing to run and spewing out false information.

You can catch a SIGSEGV with a signal handler, but say you do catch and try to handle it. Odds are the program goes right back into the code that triggered the SIGSEGV and very likely raises it again as soon as the signal handler. Or does something else weird. Possibly something worse.

It's not really even worth catching SIGSEGV with a signal handler to make an attempt to output a message, because what's the message going to say? "Oh Smurf. Something very bad happened."?

So, yes, you can catch it, but you can't do anything to recover. The program is already too damaged to continue. That leaves preventing SIGSEGV in the first place, and that means fixing your code.

The best thing you can do is determine why the program crashed. The easiest way to do that is run your program with [whatever debugger came with your development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger), wait for the crash, then inspect the backtrace for hints on how the program came to meet its doom.

Typically a link to [Eric Lippert's How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) can be found right about here, and I can't think of a good reason to leave it out.

One other thing, though. cURL is a pretty  solid library. Odds are overwhelmingly good that you are using it wrong or passed it bad information: a dead pointer, an unterminated C-style string, an pointer to an explosive function. I'd start by looking at how you are using cURL.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. Instead, fix the bug and prevent the segmentation fault that way. Presumably your platform supplies some kind of debugger.